# ggplot2 in R too slow

Tags: r

I'm trying to use ggplot2 to draw a graph

`library(tidyverse)
 plot1<-ggplot(data = data1) +
        geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x1, y = y1, shape =s1))`

My data contains millions of observations, so when I use this command, the computer becomes irresponsive for 1 minute, I don't know how to address this? Is there any way to draw graphs faster? Does Microsoft R Open help? (In ggplot2 and data processing?)

Comment: Subsample your data to get a meaningful representation, then plot that subsample instead.

Comment: Yep. A million `grid` `grob`s is going to be super slow. RStudio is working on ravamping `ggplot2` internals and possibly `grid` to fix this but you need to sample or use something like scatterplot smoothing https://www.inwt-statistics.com/read-blog/smoothscatter-with-ggplot2-513.html